# How do I access an iPads Document Directory through an NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am building an app that uses core data to store objects internally, and the URL for document directory is always returning nill.

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

What am I doing incorrectly, or am I no where close to where I need to be?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use NSCachesDirectory if this data can be downloaded again.
Or NSApplicationSupportDirectory if this data can't be restored.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This should be comment (though I don't know why you make this recommendation).